# error with struts2 tag usage in html

Tags: struts2

My struts 2 Serverside action has a method

```
public boolean isHomeAddress() {
    return true;
}
```

My view (html) contains  the below code

```
<@s.if test="${homeAddress == true}"> dosomething </@s.if>
<@s.elseif test="someexpression"> else worked </@s.elseif>
<@s.else> no condition passed</@s.else>
```

I get the error

```
----
Tip: If you just want "true"/"false" result as you are generting computer-language output, use "?c", like ${myBool?c}.
----
Tip: You can write myBool?string('yes', 'no') and like to specify boolean formatting in place.
----
Tip: If you need the same two values on most places, the programmers should set the "boolean_format" setting to something like "yes,no".


----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${homeAddress == true}  [in template "freemarker/myaccount/mobile/orderTracking.html" at line 132, column 30]
    - Reached through: @s.if test="\${homeAddress == true}"  [in template "freemarker/myaccount/mobile/orderTracking.html" at line 132, column 17]
```

Comment: should i use <@s.if test="${homeAddress == 'true'}"> dosomething </@s.if>    instead

Comment: Why not just `homeAddress`?

Comment: <@s.if test="${homeAddress}"> dosomething </@s.if>

Comment: <@s.if test="%{homeAddress}"> dosomething </@s.if>    worked finally

Comment: not related to this question but is `<@s.if` a correct syntax in jsp ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
<@s.if test="%{homeAddress}"> dosomething </@s.if>
```

worked finally